# Создание шаблона функции по аргументам другой функции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, метапрограммирование

Извне я получаю массив union структур с параметрами, которые хочу передать предварительно сохраненному указателю на функцию.

В связи с этим встал вопрос: возможно ли силами шаблона создать некоторую прокси-функцию, которая будет на основании списка аргументов сохраненного указателя на функцию распаковывать изначальный массив?

Т.е. создавая шаблонную реализацию класса с указателем функции

```
//Ret(*foo)(Args... args)
int foo(std::string, int)
```

я буду генерировать в нем метод

```
int bar(SomeThing* params)
{
    return foo(Unpack<std::string>(params[0]), Unpack<int>(params[1]));
}
```

UPD:
Пример кода с учетом комментариев.

```
template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
class Interface : public Base
{
public:
    Interface(Ret(*function)(Args... args)) : function_(function) { }

    void Invoke(SomeThing* params, SomeThing* result)
    {
        Pack<Ret>(result, function_(Unpack(params)...));
    }

private:
    Ret(*function_)(Args... args);
};
```

UPD 2:
Предполагаемое использование.

```
std::map<std::string, Base> map;
map.insert("Test", new Interface<A(*)(B,C,D)>(&foo));
...
map["Test"]->Invoke(params, result);
```

Comment: Что значит "... создавая шаблонную реализацию класса с указателем функции"? Также: `void* params` и затем `params[0]`? Но оператор `[]` неприменим к указателю типа `void *`.

Comment: 1. Указатель функции содержится в прокси-классе, от общего родителя, что бы сложить все в один контейнер и вызывать виртуальный ProxyClass::Invoke(void* params) наследников.
Т.е. фраза значит: new ProxyClass<&foo>() вы коде

2. void это указательна массив union структур, поскольку в рамках вопроса конкретный тип не важен, я подставил void, на деле там будет некий SomeThing*

Comment: @АндрейЖбанников Не надо описывать код словами, приведите минимальный пример, демонстрирующий предполагаемое использование. А то у вас сейчас полная каша - то шаблон функции, то шаблон класса, то виртуальный метод.

Comment: @Андрей Жбанников: Приведите определение `ProxyClass`. Если у вас можно делать `ProxyClass<&foo>`, то совершенно непонятно, как и откуда возьмутся неизвестные `Ret` и `Args...`.

Comment: @AnT отредактировал вопрос, загвоздка в этой некоторой функции unpack или ином способе передачи параметров.
Прошу прощения, ProxyClass<Ret(*)(Args...)>( &foo) конечно же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дано:

- Структура которая хранит в себе информацию чтобы сконструировать любой необходимый тип:

  ```
  struct SomeThing{
      //...
  };
  ```
- Функция, которая способна сконструировать любой необходимый тип:

  ```
  template<class T>
  T unpack(const SomeThing &){
      std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
      return T();
  }
  ```

  Кстати, если добавить в структуру с данными метод `template<class T> operator T() const`, то такой функцией будет `static_cast`
- Функция, которую нужно вызвать:

  ```
  struct Bar{

  };

  int foo(int, double, const Bar &){
      return 42;
  }
  ```
- Вызов

  ```
  int main(){
      SomeThing params[10];

      int answer = call(foo, params);
      std::cout << answer << std::endl;
  }
  ```

---

Решение:

При помощи [`std::index_sequence_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) генерируем последовательность индексов(1, 2, 3 ...) равную по длинне списку аргументов. И при помощи конструкции

```
foo(unpack<std::decay_t<Args>>(params[indexes])...);
```

заставляем компилятор сгенерировать что-то вроде этого:

```
foo(unpack<std::decay_t<Arg1>>(params[1]), std::decay_t<Arg2>>(params[2]), ...);
```

[Полный код:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a537d7af2a9b041)

```
template<class Ret, class ...Args, std::size_t ...indexes>
Ret call(Ret(*func)(Args...), SomeThing *params, const std::index_sequence<indexes...> &){
    return func(unpack<std::decay_t<Args>>(params[indexes])...);
}

template<class Ret, class... Args>
Ret call(Ret(*func)(Args...), SomeThing *params ){
    return call(func, params, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>());
}
```

---

В коде есть риск вылететь за границы массива, что, по сути, является неопределнным поведением. В моем примере размер массива известен на этапе компиляции, так что можно передать массив по ссылке, и ввернуть `static_assert` внутри `call`. Но в общем случае `prams` может быть алоцирован в куче, поэтому я эту проверку добавлять не стал.

[Пример с проверкой выхода за границы массива:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7ad5b0fc7c23f66)

```
template<class Ret, class ...Args, std::size_t ...indexes, std::size_t size>
Ret call(Ret(*func)(Args...), SomeThing (&params)[size], const std::index_sequence<indexes...> &){
    static_assert(sizeof...(indexes) <= size, "array \"params\" is too small");
    return func(unpack<std::decay_t<Args>>(params[indexes])...);
}

template<class Ret, class... Args, std::size_t size>
Ret call(Ret(*func)(Args...), SomeThing (&params)[size]){
    return call(func, params, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>());
}
```

Такой код более безопасный, но вот с динамическими масивам работать не будет

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял проблема в том что иметь номер параметра, извлекаемого из контейнера сериализации (в твоем случае - void*) - недостаточно. Нужно, либо чтобы функции unpack применялись к контейнеру в заданом порядке, либо чтобы unpack знал обо всех остальных типах, хранимых в контейнере. 2-й подход ИМХО проще.

Например, если твой SomeThing`* - указатель на соответствующий std::tuple:

```
typedef void  SomeThing;

template< typename ...T >
std::tuple<T...>* unpack_tuple(SomeThing* p)
{
    return static_cast< std::tuple<T...>* >(p); // Возможно, что-то более сложное
}

template< typename R, typename ... T , size_t ... i >
R imple_invoke( R (*fn)(T...), std::tuple<T...>* p , std::integer_sequence<size_t, i...> )
{
    return fn(  std::get<i>(*p)... ) ;
}

template< typename R, typename ... T >
R invoke( R (*fn)(T...), SomeThing *p )
{
    return imple_invoke(fn, unpack_tuple<T...>(p), std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)> () );
}
```

Твой Invoke:

```
void Invoke(SomeThing* params, SomeThing* result)
{
    Pack<Ret>(result, invoke(function_, params) ));
}
```